# は vs なら in this sentence

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nuances

I'm trying to understand the difference between は and なら in these two sentences.

> 彼はきっと大丈夫。

> 彼ならきっと大丈夫。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This なら is basically a condition marker like "if". So a literal translation is something like "If it's *he*, (he) will be okay".

It's used typically in two situations:

- The speaker wants to confirm the topic using なら: "(Oh, so you're talking about *him*? If that's the case, then) he will be okay."
- The speaker is thinking he is special ("he" is the condition of the remaining part of the sentence): "(Other people may not be able to do this, but if it's *he* who tries it,) he will be okay."